# Sails.js - How to have a unique session for each browser tab

Tags: sails.js

When I run a Sails app from a browser tab I get a unique session in which you can store authentication information.  If you start the same application in a different browser tab, the session is identical and is therefore already authenticated.  Although useful, I don't want that.  I want each browser tab to have a completely unique session.  Is this possible and if so, how?   How is the sails.sid generated?   I thought maybe I could generate a unique secret but of course the time my code gets a look in it is too late.

Obviously I don't have to use req.session at all, and generate my own unique identifier and store for each tab, but want to make use of standard sessions if I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a unique session for each tab in the same browser instance.
The way the session works is not suitable for what you want to achieve.

One solution is to use a socket to identify the tab. Caution, you can not reload the page, cause every time you will get a new socket.

Comment: Kinda reached the same conclusion over the last 24 hours.  You can actually have a unique session per tab using other platforms, but it just doesn't fly in Sails/Express.  I have opted for JWT instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need **dirty hack** here.

1. Every tab has their unique **socketId**,
2. So you can use this **socketId** as a **sessionId**.
3. `beforeConnect()` handle logic for `socketId = sessionId` & store it somewhere if needed.
4. `afterDisconnect()` handle logic for remove **session** from storage.

> NOTE: **Tab refresh** create new session always because refresh means open
>   **new tab** within current tab itself.

Comment: Yes I guess that is what the previous answer from @angelos alluded to. I know I can roll my own tab specific sessions and I have achieved that, but I was really trying to find out if it was possible with the out of the box sessions provided by express but it seems not.